# Web browser automation loop and stop (+notification) when some phrase is no more displayed on the page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to take an appointment on a website, but it keeps showing me that "there is no more places for appointments".

So i would like to run some kind of chrome extension as so:

1. Connect to a web adress
2. check some boxes, click on a button
3. On the next page if the phrase "there is no more places..." is not displayed on the page, that would mean some kind of form is displayed for appointment.
4. The script stops and send me a notification, if nothing changed then restart from (1) after let's say 5mins.

Any solution for that purpose?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it's clear enough. Well it is some kind of loop program that i'm looking for. It'll have to click on a button, check boxes and on the next page look if there is a specific phrase displayed or not. if not then the program stops and send me a notification so i can get my appointment.
I'm not asking for a free service. Maybe i'm on the wrong plateform...